# And the sun of mercy shall rise with healing in its wings

Tags: messiah, book-of-malachi

Malachi 3:20:
And the sun of mercy shall rise with healing in its wings for you who fear My Name. Then will you go forth and be fat as fatted calves.
        וְזָרְחָה לָכֶם יִרְאֵי שְׁמִי שֶׁמֶשׁ צְדָקָה וּמַרְפֵּא בִּכְנָפֶיהָ וִיצָאתֶם וּפִשְׁתֶּם כְּעֶגְלֵי מַרְבֵּק:‏
21: And you shall crush the wicked, for they will be as ash under the soles of your feet on the day that I will prepare, says the Lord of Hosts.
        וְעַסּוֹתֶם רְשָׁעִים כִּי יִהְיוּ אֵפֶר תַּחַת כַּפּוֹת רַגְלֵיכֶם בַּיּוֹם אֲשֶׁר אֲנִי עֹשֶׂה אָמַר יְהֹוָה צְבָאוֹת

Is Malachi talking about the Moshiach? And what is *healing in his wings*?

Answer (score 4):

Verse 20 is connected to [verse 19](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16221#showrashi=true) which says:

> “For lo, the sun comes, glowing like a furnace, and all the audacious
>   sinners and all the perpetrators of wickedness will be stubble. And
>   the sun that comes shall burn them up so that it will leave them
>   neither root nor branch, says the Lord of Hosts.”

Rashi explains:

> “This instance of יוֹם is an expression of sun, for so did the Sages
>   state that there will be no Gehinnom in the future, but the Holy One,
>   blessed be He, will take the sun out of its case; the wicked will be
>   punished thereby and the righteous will be healed thereby. That is the
>   meaning of what is stated (verse 20): “And the sun of mercy shall rise
>   for you who fear My Name, etc.”

[The Malbim explains](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39981&st=&pgnum=293):

> “that for those that fear My Name, the righteous who serve out of
>   love, there will be mercy  through the good deeds that they did. This
>   explains the words “שֶׁמֶשׁ צְדָקָה". This sun will heal through its
>   wings, which means its burning heat. It will reveal the righteous and
>   destroy the wicked.”

The [Redak and the Metzudos Dovid](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=420&hilite=) compares the sun's rays to protective wings.

So Malachi does not seem to be talking about Moshiach.

“Healing in his wings” seems to be a poetic reference to the beneficial effect of the sun on the righteous.

Comment: off course its poetic,but who/what is the sun?It cant be sun light.<The sun light will make them stumble?"The righteous will be heald!(Vitamin C?)

Comment: @Aigle It’s absolutely the sun. Can we go back to the part where the sun is “taken out of its sheath” (i.e. is made much hotter)?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but maybe someone will find this helpful...

The OP must be right that it is Moshiach.  There are other places with similar language about the sun:

Psalm 84 תְּהִלִּים
יב  כִּי שֶׁמֶשׁ, וּמָגֵן--    יְהוָה אֱלֹהִים:
חֵן וְכָבוֹד,    יִתֵּן יְהוָה;
לֹא יִמְנַע-טוֹב,    לַהֹלְכִים בְּתָמִים.  12 For the LORD God is a sun and a shield; {N}
the LORD giveth grace and glory; {N}
no good thing will He withhold from them that walk uprightly.

Here we see that Hashem is called a sun "שֶׁמֶשׁ".

ה  וְנַסְתֶּם גֵּיא-הָרַי, כִּי-יַגִּיעַ גֵּי-הָרִים אֶל-אָצַל, וְנַסְתֶּם כַּאֲשֶׁר נַסְתֶּם מִפְּנֵי הָרַעַשׁ, בִּימֵי עֻזִּיָּה מֶלֶךְ-יְהוּדָה; וּבָא יְהוָה אֱלֹהַי, כָּל-קְדֹשִׁים עִמָּךְ.   5 And ye shall flee to the valley of the mountains; for the valley of the mountains shall reach unto Azel; yea, ye shall flee, like as ye fled from before the earthquake in the days of Uzziah king of Judah; and the LORD my God shall come, and all the holy ones with Thee.

Here we learn that Hashem will come and save Israel from the big battle described in the chapter.  Will he come in person?  This cannot be true because we also read:

Exodus Chapter 33 שְׁמוֹת
כ  וַיֹּאמֶר, לֹא תוּכַל לִרְאֹת אֶת-פָּנָי:  כִּי לֹא-יִרְאַנִי הָאָדָם, וָחָי.    20 And He said: 'Thou canst not see My face, for man shall not see Me and live.'

Ribbi Yehudah in Sefer ha-kozari explains that verse this way:
'Of that divine glory mentioned in the scripture, there is one degree which the eyes of the prophets were able to explore; another which all the Israelites saw, as the cloud and consuming fire; the third is so bright, and so dazzling, that no mortal is able to comprehend it; but should anyone venture to look on it, his whole frame would be dissolved.'

Would a sun be a fitting description?  I think so.

Is such a being going to walk the earth?

It seems better to understand it as he saved Israel in the past because we also read:

Zechariah Chapter 14 זְכַרְיָה
ג  וְיָצָא יְהוָה, וְנִלְחַם בַּגּוֹיִם הָהֵם, כְּיוֹם הִלָּחֲמוֹ, בְּיוֹם קְרָב.   3 Then shall the LORD go forth, and fight against those nations, as when He fighteth in the day of battle.

So it is to be as it was in the past, but in our day.  How did he fight the nations for Israel in the past?  He sent a human, be it Moshe, Yehoshua ben Nun, Gideon... He wrought salvation by their hand.  He also turned the sword of the wicked against his brother, which we read will also happen again.  Kind of like in Syria.

Also, the latter verses of Zechariah are clearly the messianic age.

Note too, the verses just after in Malachi:

כא  וְעַסּוֹתֶם רְשָׁעִים--כִּי-יִהְיוּ אֵפֶר, תַּחַת כַּפּוֹת רַגְלֵיכֶם:  בַּיּוֹם אֲשֶׁר אֲנִי עֹשֶׂה, אָמַר יְהוָה צְבָאוֹת.  {פ}   21 And ye shall tread down the wicked; for they shall be ashes under the soles of your feet in the day that I do make, saith the LORD of hosts. {P}
כב  זִכְרוּ, תּוֹרַת מֹשֶׁה עַבְדִּי, אֲשֶׁר צִוִּיתִי אוֹתוֹ בְחֹרֵב עַל-כָּל-יִשְׂרָאֵל, חֻקִּים וּמִשְׁפָּטִים.  22 Remember ye the law of Moses My servant, which I commanded unto him in Horeb for all Israel, even statutes and ordinances.
כג  הִנֵּה אָנֹכִי שֹׁלֵחַ לָכֶם, אֵת אֵלִיָּה הַנָּבִיא--לִפְנֵי, בּוֹא יוֹם יְהוָה, הַגָּדוֹל, וְהַנּוֹרָא.   23 Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet before the coming of the great and terrible day of the LORD.
כד  וְהֵשִׁיב לֵב-אָבוֹת עַל-בָּנִים, וְלֵב בָּנִים עַל-אֲבוֹתָם--פֶּן-אָבוֹא, וְהִכֵּיתִי אֶת-הָאָרֶץ חֵרֶם.  {ש}  24 And he shall turn the heart of the fathers to the children, and the heart of the children to their fathers; lest I come and smite the land with utter destruction. {P}

Eliyahu comes right before Moshiach.  This coming is necessary to "turn the heart", to bring about teshuva so that the "sun" doesn't burn everyone up with "utter destruction".

Many can be saved on behalf of few:

Genesis Chapter 18 בְּרֵאשִׁית
לב  וַיֹּאמֶר אַל-נָא יִחַר לַאדֹנָי, וַאֲדַבְּרָה אַךְ-הַפַּעַם--אוּלַי יִמָּצְאוּן שָׁם, עֲשָׂרָה; וַיֹּאמֶר לֹא אַשְׁחִית, בַּעֲבוּר הָעֲשָׂרָה. 32 And he said: 'Oh, let not the LORD be angry, and I will speak yet but this once. Peradventure ten shall be found there.' And He said: 'I will not destroy it for the ten's sake.'

So the work of Eliyahu doesn't necessarily need to bring all to teshuva.

So, in summary:

- The verses after are the Messianic age.
- Hashem is called a sun in the Psalms.
- Hashem will save Israel by the hand of Moshiach.
- The coming of Moshiach to save is called the coming of Hashem in Zech. (The work of Hashem through men is often referred to as things done by Hashem, why not here?)
- Why not see this arising of the sun of righteousness "שֶׁמֶשׁ צְדָקָה" as Moshiach?

B"H

Comment: Interesting answer, but, this does go against the words passed down from our Sages cited in the other answer.